# More than one app is listening for the URL scheme defined for BrowserTabActivity in the AndroidManifest

Tags: java, android, mobile, azure-ad-msal

Mobile App for Android. Java. Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1.

When I try to create a new PublicClientApplication entity, this error appears
MSALApplication created ERROR:
*com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException: More than one app is listening for the URL scheme defined for BrowserTabActivity in the AndroidManifest. The package name of this other app is: com.android.chrome*

The customer company redirects to its website and this, as I understand it, is the main problem. But still maybe there is some solution? I want it to work from the system browser since I need SSO later

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:exported="true"
    android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host=“mysite”/>
       

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Config for msal(PublicClientApplication)

```
{
  "client_id" : “app id”,
  "redirect_uri" : "https://mysite",
  "broker_redirect_uri_registered": true,
  "authorization_user_agent": “BROWSER”, 
  "account_mode" : "SINGLE",
  "logging": {
    "pii_enabled": false,
    "log_level": "VERBOSE",
    "logcat_enabled": true
  },
  "authorities" : [
    {
      "type": "AAD",
      "audience": {
        "type": "AzureADMyOrg",
        "tenant_id": "tenant_id"
      },
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "browser_safelist": [
    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.android.chrome",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "7fmduHKTdHHrlMvldlEqAIlSfii1tl35bxj1OXN5Ve8c4lU6URVu4xtSHc3BVZxS6WWJnxMDhIfQN0N0K2NDJg=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : true

    },
    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.android.chrome",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "7fmduHKTdHHrlMvldlEqAIlSfii1tl35bxj1OXN5Ve8c4lU6URVu4xtSHc3BVZxS6WWJnxMDhIfQN0N0K2NDJg=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    },
    {
      "browser_package_name": "org.mozilla.firefox",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "2gCe6pR_AO_Q2Vu8Iep-4AsiKNnUHQxu0FaDHO_qa178GByKybdT_BuE8_dYk99G5Uvx_gdONXAOO2EaXidpVQ=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    },
    {
      "browser_package_name": "org.mozilla.firefox",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "2gCe6pR_AO_Q2Vu8Iep-4AsiKNnUHQxu0FaDHO_qa178GByKybdT_BuE8_dYk99G5Uvx_gdONXAOO2EaXidpVQ=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : true,
      "browser_version_lower_bound": "57"
    },
    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.sec.android.app.sbrowser",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "ABi2fbt8vkzj7SJ8aD5jc4xJFTDFntdkMrYXL3itsvqY1QIw-dZozdop5rgKNxjbrQAd5nntAGpgh9w84O1Xgg=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : true,
      "browser_version_lower_bound": "4.0"
    },
    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.sec.android.app.sbrowser",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "ABi2fbt8vkzj7SJ8aD5jc4xJFTDFntdkMrYXL3itsvqY1QIw-dZozdop5rgKNxjbrQAd5nntAGpgh9w84O1Xgg=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    },
    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.cloudmosa.puffinFree",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "1WqG8SoK2WvE4NTYgr2550TRhjhxT-7DWxu6C_o6GrOLK6xzG67Hq7GCGDjkAFRCOChlo2XUUglLRAYu3Mn8Ag=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    },
    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.duckduckgo.mobile.android",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "S5Av4cfEycCvIvKPpKGjyCuAE5gZ8y60-knFfGkAEIZWPr9lU5kA7iOAlSZxaJei08s0ruDvuEzFYlmH-jAi4Q=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    },
    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.explore.web.browser",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "BzDzBVSAwah8f_A0MYJCPOkt0eb7WcIEw6Udn7VLcizjoU3wxAzVisCm6bW7uTs4WpMfBEJYf0nDgzTYvYHCag=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    },

    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.ksmobile.cb",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "lFDYx1Rwc7_XUn4KlfQk2klXLufRyuGHLa3a7rNjqQMkMaxZueQfxukVTvA7yKKp3Md3XUeeDSWGIZcRy7nouw=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    },

    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.microsoft.emmx",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "Ivy-Rk6ztai_IudfbyUrSHugzRqAtHWslFvHT0PTvLMsEKLUIgv7ZZbVxygWy_M5mOPpfjZrd3vOx3t-cA6fVQ=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    },

    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.opera.browser",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "FIJ3IIeqB7V0qHpRNEpYNkhEGA_eJaf7ntca-Oa_6Feev3UkgnpguTNV31JdAmpEFPGNPo0RHqdlU0k-3jWJWw=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    },

    {
      "browser_package_name": "com.opera.mini.native",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "TOTyHs086iGIEdxrX_24aAewTZxV7Wbi6niS2ZrpPhLkjuZPAh1c3NQ_U4Lx1KdgyhQE4BiS36MIfP6LbmmUYQ=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    },

    {
      "browser_package_name": "mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "RMVoXuK1sfJZuGZ8onG1yhMc-sKiAV2NiB_GZfdNlN8XJ78XEE2wPM6LnQiyltF25GkHiPN2iKQiGwaO2bkyyQ=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    },

    {
      "browser_package_name": "org.mozilla.focus",
      "browser_signature_hashes": [
        "L72dT-stFqomSY7sYySrgBJ3VYKbipMZapmUXfTZNqOzN_dekT5wdBACJkpz0C6P0yx5EmZ5IciI93Q0hq0oYA=="
      ],
      "browser_use_customTab" : false
    }
  ]
}
```

I try:
"broker_redirect_uri_registered": true->false, no effect

"authorization_user_agent": “BROWSER” -> WEBVIEW, all work, but if I understand correctly, then there will be no SSO

if change intent-filter to

```
android:scheme="msauth"
android:host="login.microsoftonline.com"
android:path="/tenant_id"/\>
```

but not change redirect in config the same error occurs
if change config - Azure send error what this route unavailable for this customer

Answer (score 0):

You need the following data inside your `intent-filter`

```
<data android:scheme="msauth"
 android:host="Enter_the_Package_Name"
 android:path="/Enter_the_Signature_Hash" />
```

If you use any other package name, Graph API will not accept

Comment: thanks for the reply. Now the project has already been submitted with WEBVIEW and I will not return to it soon. I tried your option, but the difficulty there is that msauth is not configured for a redirect from the customer. Therefore, it is necessary to solve it comprehensively and configure the azura correctly, but the customer did not want to, and I did not have access to it